# file_get_content not working for https in php

Tags: php, file-get-contents, tls1.2

Has anybody had an issue with display content from a website thats over https? The code was working until all the sites on server got ssl. maybe something to so with the certificate being tlss 1.2? So the site im trying to do this from has this certificate now.

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.ladygaga.com/'); 
echo $data;
```

Comment: I have tried your code and its working perfectly.

Comment: yeah im assuming your environment or ssl is different? im using php 5.3

Comment: if i replace the url with https://www.google.com this works :s

Comment: Try to get new cert: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: sorry what am i suppose to do this with, im not familiar with php

Comment: im using iis if that makes a difference

Comment: Check this [how to get the certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [php.net](https://www.php.net)

> When using SSL, Microsoft IIS will violate the protocol by closing the
>   connection without sending a close_notify indicator. PHP will report
>   this as "SSL: Fatal Protocol Error" when you reach the end of the
>   data. To work around this, the value of error_reporting should be
>   lowered to a level that does not include warnings. PHP can detect
>   buggy IIS server software when you open the stream using the https://
>   wrapper and will suppress the warning. When using fsockopen() to
>   create an ssl:// socket, the developer is responsible for detecting
>   and suppressing this warning.

[Source link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: hmmm do you know how to get around this then? I have reduced the errors no success

Comment: You can use try...catch block.

Answer (score 0):

[Based on OpenSSL changes in PHP 5.6](https://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php), try this:

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  

$response = file_get_contents("https://www.ladygaga.com/", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));

echo $response;
```

Another option would be to use curl as such:

```
function file_get_contents_curl( $url ) {

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );

  $data = curl_exec( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );

  return $data;

}

$data = file_get_contents_curl("https://www.ladygaga.com");
```

Comment: or if i try bbc.com etc

Comment: Good temporary solution using curl 